# ¿Es posible mostrar una etiqueta oculta dentro de un enlace que haya sido visitado?

Tags: html, css

pues me explico. Resulta que estoy diseñando algo en css y quiero que al momento de un enlace haya sido visitado, éste muestre una etiqueta (span, div u otra).

Dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero:

```
<style>
a {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a span {color: red}
a:visited {background: blue;}
a:visited span {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<a href="#url32">
    texto de ejemplo
    <span>visto</span>
</a>
```

En teoría debería de por lo menos mostrarse el texto en azul, no sé si será problema de mi navegador o algo. La verdad estoy estancado con esto.
Cualquier ayuda, se agradecerá.

Answer (score 0):

No se si puedas hacer esto con css, pero lo puedes hacer con JavaScript, esto lo puedes hacer si quieres que al dar click en un elemento, otro elemento que no sea hijo de este elemento cambie

```
var elemento_1 = document.getElementById("Id_del_elemento_1");
var elemento_2 = document.getElementById("Id_del_elemento_2");
elemento_1.addEventListener("click", nombre_de_la_función)
function nombre_de_la_función (){
  elemento_2.style.display = "none";
  //Aquí puedes agregar más estilos
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: La verdad no es lo que busco en sí, de hecho es algo diferente. Me explico mejor: Tengo una etiqueta <a> y dentro de esta una etiqueta <span>, esta etiqueta <span> se encuentra oculta, pero quiero que al momento que se haya visitado dicho enlace, la etiqueta <span> se muestre visible con :visited, justo como sale en el ejemplo que puse. ¿Se entiende? Lo que no entiendo es porque no me toma los demás estilos (cambiar de color el fondo y eso, ya que en sí debería de mostrarse).

Answer (score 0):

Mira tu código editado con una función de JavaScript.

```js
function linkVisitado(){
  let link = document.getElementById('visitado');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = "visto";
  link.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
a {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
color: red
}

a:visited {
color: blue;
}
a:visited span {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a onclick = "linkVisitado()" id="visitado" href="#42r">
  Texto de prueba
</a>
```

según tengo entendido lo que quieres hacer es que cambie de color, entonces solo es poner la propiedad color en vez de la propiedad background.

```css
a {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
color: red
}

a:hover {
color: blue;
}

a:visited span {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#url32">
    texto de ejemplo
    <span>visto</span>
</a
```

Comment: La verdad no es lo que busco, amigo. mira arriba, allí deje un comentario explicando mejor lo que busco. Gracias de todos modos.